# MySQL error when trying to read from database in PHP/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

In my application I am getting the following error when trying to get data from MySQL. I'm not sure if it is a misconfiguration of MySQL, if someone could check my code for me and tell me how MySQL should look it will be greatly appreciated.

The error that I am receiving is Could not query: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'. This only displays once I select an item from the drop down box.

Here is the code for the main page which has the drop down box on it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cable Management</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<?php include("Header.php"); ?>
    <div id="main">
         <h1>Cable Management</h1>
         <h2>Bournemouth Office</h2>
         <p>Enter how many cables you want to remove or add from the Bournemouth office</p>
        <script>
            function showcables(str)
            {
                if (str == "")
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                    return;
                }

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else // code for IE6, IE5
                {
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET","getcable.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
       </script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" NAME='amount' VALUE ="">
<select name="cables" onchange="showcables(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a cable type</option>
<option value="0.25 Metre Orange">0.25 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="0.3 Metre Orange">0.3 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="0.5 Metre Orange">0.5 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="1 Metre Orange">1 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="2 Metre Orange">2 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="3 Metre Orange">3 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="5 Metre Orange">5 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="10 Metre Orange">10 Metre Orange</option>
<option value="2 Metre Black">2 Metre Black</option>
<option value="3 Metre Black">3 Metre Black</option>
<option value="5 Metre Black">5 Metre Black</option>
<option value="10 Metre Black">10 Metre Black</option>
<option value="RJ 11">RJ11</option>
<option value="RJ 11 to BT">RJ11 to BT</option>
</select>
<INPUT TYPE = "button" Name = "Remove" VALUE = "Remove">
<INPUT TYPE = "button" Name = "Add" VALUE = "Add">
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>The amount of cables left will be listed here</b></div>

        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-clear"></div><!-- add this at the end of wrapper -->
</div> <!-- i added this closing tag, it was missing (for wrapper) -->
<?php include("Footer.php"); ?> <!-- move footer to go outside of wrapper -->
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the getcable.php page which actually has the MySQL commands in it

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cables');
if (!$con)
  {
  die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }


$sql="SELECT * FROM bmouthoff WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Could not query: " . mysqli_error($con));

echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Amount'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: check the table again, sure the column isnt actually named ld (LD) ?

Comment: may be id column is not there.

Comment: could you show a script of your data table? do you have a column named id? are your id values the strings like '0.25 Metre Orange'?

Comment: Sorry, MySQL is not my strong point at all. I am using PHPmyadmin and I have created a database called cables. A table called bmouthoff and a Column called ID. My column wasn't called ID I am not getting this error anymore. Do I not need to add each column as the full name as in the drop down box? How can I get some dummy data to test? 

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Your table seems not to have a column called `id`, therefore your query fails.

```
SELECT * FROM `bmouthoff` WHERE `id` = 'youridexample';
```

The error message...

> Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'.

...says it all.

Check out the table definition and replace `id` with the actual column name you want there, or rename the column in your table to `id`.

Answer (score 1):

R u kidding ? 
value="RJ 11 to BT" This value isn't integer at all. Cannot be converted to int also with the intval funct.
Unfortunetely
I can not see if there is a null controll for the id ?

```
$q = isset($_REQUEST["id"]) ? $_REQUEST["id"] : null ;
if($q != null)
{
}
```

work better .
What is the type of ID column ? Is int ? So the escaper of ' ' is useless.

Comment: Sorry I think there may be a problem with the way my application is working then. The idea is that when a certain cable from the drop down box is selected, it connects to MySQL and gets a number of cables that are set for that selected cable type. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In query

```
SELECT * FROM bmouthoff WHERE id = '".$q."'"
```

you send value of cables select, wich is not integer.